# Preg_grep() Regex pattern is not working as expected

Tags: php

I have the following code and I'm trying to achieve an effect like this
-Remove the "-" and number from the end of the string.
-Then check if the value is matching or not.
Here's my **PHP** code

```
$usernames= array("microsoft-2","google-1","google");
$value='google';

$input = preg_quote($value, '~');
$result = preg_grep('~' . $value . '~', $usernames);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
//Array
(
    [1] => google-1
    [2] => google
)
```

The above results are fine but the problem is If I set value as **"goog"** it returns the same result while I'm expecting it to return an empty erray.
The usernames are coming from database and can be a large number.
In short it should return an remove the dash and number at the end and afterwards it should check if the values are same or not. If yes, then push in results otherwise not.
Any help would be appreciated ! Many Thanks

Comment: Add a trailing anchor prior to the closing delimiter, `$`.

Comment: `preg_grep('~' . $value . '\b~', $usernames);`  Add word breaks.

Comment: @user3783243 - in the case of `google-1` the `$` will not produce the correct result.  `The above results are fine`, or in English `google` would no longer match `google-1`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I think you misread. `If I set value as "goog" it returns the same result while I'm expecting it to return an empty erray`. So `goog` should not match any of them.

Comment: @user3783243 This was not producing the correct result as ArtisticPhoenix quoted. This was failing on value "google" as well for some reason

Comment: `as well for some reason` - `google$` is not `google-1`  as the `$` means end, and that ends in `-1` not `le`  with a word break `\b` it matches up to `\W` or not `[a-z0-9_]`  Which in this case is the `-` in `google-1` so `google\b` does indeed match `google`  minus the `-1`

Comment: I quoted in the question that I want to remove the dash and number from the end and then compare it. Anyways Thanks @user3783243 for your time :)

Comment: You're asking why your code doesn't work but you only show the code that does work. Please extract a [mcve]!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt So only the code which is throwing tons of errors should be posted here? I thought there are also some logical errors which never throws errors and always WORK !

Comment: @MuhammadOsama indeed there are such as `if($foo = 'hello world')` instead of `if($foo == 'hello world')`  or getting exclusive Or's confused `($foo && $bar || $bis)` instead of `($foo && ($bar || $bis))`  etc.  None of which by itself is an error.

Comment: Yes thats very true. But I still think my question is completely valid with a perfectly verifiable example.

Comment: Well I have seen some debate about answering Regex questions where the pattern is wrong.  But I don't mind answering them.

Comment: No, it's not supposed to throw tons of errors but exactly one. The point is, that everyone should be able to take your code and throw it at PHP for reproduction easily. Your handwaving "if I change this and that" doesn't help. That said, I don't know what *you* mean with that second sentence of your response. Either there is an error or it works, an error that works seems like a contradiction and without a clearer definition it's hard to argue.

Comment: I would love if you can edit this question to a constructive question so it can help others too ! As I can't think how to rephrase this from "If I change this and that" to something constructive. Your Help needed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add word break `\b`

```
$usernames= array("microsoft-2","google-1","google");
$value='goog';

$input = preg_quote($value, '~');
$result = preg_grep('~' . $value . '\b~', $usernames);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
array()
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31ed08cfe31fa432271f6956de9e0d71bc4511d8)

You can even add one to each side `$result = preg_grep('~\b' . $value . '\b~', $usernames);` in this case `goog` you only need the right one.

Comment: Sure you can even match multiple words  `~\b(word1|word2|word3)\b~` etc.

Comment: I think its time to sharpen my regex skills haha, its the thing that I don't understand so much

Comment: I typically do something like this `$pattern = '~\b('.implode('|', array_map(function($word){return preg_quote($word,'~');}, $words)).')\b~i';`  Where `$words = ['one','two', '~'];` etc...

Comment: Regex can be very confusing.  It's kind of an archaic thing ... lol ... at least that's how I think of it, but it's so Powerful!  You have too look at it in the mindset of pattern matching.

Comment: I will surely learn this. No offense but the code you wrote looks like from some other world lol :D

Comment: You should see some of my other code, especially in Golfing  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151588/draw-me-a-domino/151599#151599   Golfing is trying to do something in as few bytes as possible.

Comment: I will surely check this. Thanks a lot ! :)